# Spring StateMachineFactory getStateMachine returns currents state as initial state

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-statemachine

I working with Spring State Machines. I followed the documentation and other stuff. I need to keep different state machines for each employee. But when called factory to get state machine each time returns a state machine whose state is initial.

```
public enum EmployeeEvent {
    CREATED, CHECKSTARTED, APPROVE, ACTIVATED
}

public enum EmployeeState {
    ADDED, INCHECK, APPROVED, ACTIVE
}
```

States are events like above. Configuration is below

```
@Configuration
@EnableStateMachineFactory
public class StateMachineConfig extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<EmployeeState, EmployeeEvent> {

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<EmployeeState, EmployeeEvent> config)
            throws Exception {
        config
                .withConfiguration()
                .autoStartup(true)
                .listener(listener());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<EmployeeState, EmployeeEvent> states)
            throws Exception {
        states
                .withStates()
                .initial(EmployeeState.ADDED)
                .states(EnumSet.allOf(EmployeeState.class))
                .end(EmployeeState.ACTIVE);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<EmployeeState, EmployeeEvent> transitions)
            throws Exception {
        transitions
                .withExternal()
                .source(EmployeeState.ADDED).target(EmployeeState.INCHECK).event(EmployeeEvent.CHECKSTARTED)
                .and()
                .withExternal()
                .source(EmployeeState.INCHECK).target(EmployeeState.APPROVED).event(EmployeeEvent.APPROVE)
                .and()
                .withExternal()
                .source(EmployeeState.APPROVED).target(EmployeeState.ACTIVE).event(EmployeeEvent.ACTIVATED);
    }

    @Bean
    public StateMachineListener<EmployeeState, EmployeeEvent> listener() {
        return new StateMachineListenerAdapter<EmployeeState, EmployeeEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(State<EmployeeState, EmployeeEvent> from, State<EmployeeState, EmployeeEvent> to) {
                System.out.println("State change to " + to.getId());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

factory build code like below

```
 private StateMachine<EmployeeState, EmployeeEvent> build(Long employeeId){
        Optional<Employee> byId = employeeRepository.findById(employeeId);
        Employee employee = byId.get();
        StateMachine<EmployeeState, EmployeeEvent> stateMachine = stateMachineFactory.getStateMachine(Long.toString(employee.getId()));
        stateMachine.stop();
        stateMachine.getStateMachineAccessor().doWithAllRegions(sma -> {
            sma.addStateMachineInterceptor(new StateMachineInterceptorAdapter<>() {
                @Override
                public void preStateChange(State<EmployeeState, EmployeeEvent> state, Message<EmployeeEvent> message, Transition<EmployeeState, EmployeeEvent> transition, StateMachine<EmployeeState, EmployeeEvent> stateMachine, StateMachine<EmployeeState, EmployeeEvent> stateMachine1) {
                    Optional.ofNullable(message).ifPresent(msg -> {
                        Long employeeId = Long.class.cast(msg.getHeaders().getOrDefault("EMPLOYEE_ID", -1));
                        Employee employee = employeeRepository.getById(employeeId);
                        employee.setState(state.getId());
                        employeeRepository.save(employee);
                    });
                }
            });
            sma.resetStateMachine(new DefaultStateMachineContext<>(EmployeeState.valueOf(employee.getState().name()), null, null,  null));
        });
        stateMachine.start();
        return stateMachine;
    }
```

But I recognized that when I called build multiple times, it returns a state machine whose state is initial. Then I wrote tests like below.

```
    @Test
    public  void sameUuid(){
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        StateMachine<EmployeeState, EmployeeEvent> stateMachine = factory.getStateMachine(uuid);
        stateMachine.sendEvent(EmployeeEvent.CHECKSTARTED);
        StateMachine<EmployeeState, EmployeeEvent> stateMachine2 = factory.getStateMachine(uuid);
        assertEquals(stateMachine.getUuid(), stateMachine2.getUuid());
        assertEquals(stateMachine.getState().getId(), stateMachine2.getState().getId());
    }
```

Uuids are the same but states are different.`

```
    @Test
    public  void sameId(){
        StateMachine<EmployeeState, EmployeeEvent> stateMachine = factory.getStateMachine("1");
        stateMachine.sendEvent(EmployeeEvent.CHECKSTARTED);
        StateMachine<EmployeeState, EmployeeEvent> stateMachine2 = factory.getStateMachine("1");
        assertEquals(stateMachine.getId(), stateMachine2.getId());
        assertEquals(stateMachine.getUuid(), stateMachine2.getUuid());
        assertEquals(stateMachine.getState().getId(), stateMachine2.getState().getId());
    }
```

Ids are the same but UUIDs are different.

I need one state machine for my one employee object. How can be solved?

Comment: was it resolved?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is `"@EnableStateMachineFactory"` When you use it you will get the new instance of the machine from context each time.
For getting singleton bean of the machine need you `@EnableStateMachine` annotation.

see more [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/index.html#sm-config)

Comment: Is it possible to distinguish states for each employee object using @EnableStateMachine?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way you retrieving state machines.

The `@EnableStateMachineFactory` annotation is used properly, but to store and restore the state machine better to use [SpringStateMachineService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/api/org/springframework/statemachine/service/StateMachineService.html) that checks if there is SM with the given ID and restore it, or creates a new one.

See the detailed answer on how to persist state machine and how to restore them from storage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63984734/spring-state-machine-with-jpa-persistence-repository-usage/63998307#63998307)