# RedisStateMachinePersister is not persisting StateMachine with Redis

Tags: spring-boot, redis, state-machine, spring-statemachine, state-machine-workflow

I am using RedisStateMachinePersister for persisting StateMachine with Redis. I can store StateMachine with below code

```
 redisPersister.persist(mc,"1");
```

redisPersister is instance of RedisStateMachinePersister. I can also see in Redis termianl that some value is stored in Redis with key "1".

[image]

But when I try to retrieve this StateMachine with same key("1") with below code, it is not getting retrieve the StateMachine object which I have stored/persisted.

```
redisPersister.restore(mc2,"1");
```

mc2 object is not same mc object which I have persisted/stored.Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions from the official documentation, you will get the job done :

1. https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.1.x/reference/html/sm-persist.html
2. https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.1.x/reference/html/statemachine-examples-eventservice.html

Edit 2023/05/14 : It seems really strange you didn't get back the record you have stored here. Some legit questions to check while thinking about your problem context :

1. Do you have multiple REDIS servers installed listening on various ports (with system packages managers and with docker too) ?
2. Do you have checked your Spring datasource configuration for REDIS ?
3. Do you use spring profiles to handle your dev/test/prod databases and your accordingly cache configs ?

Edit 2023/05/16 : Try to use any java client as jedis or lettuce to query datas from redis. It seems reading directly in-memory datas directly is not possible without using a java client, not as standard RDBMS which are allowing that

Comment: I have done same configuration as suggested but restore of state machine doesn't work.

Comment: Edited my answer to think about commons things which could lead to these kind of problem.

Comment: 1. I have only one Redis server installed.
2. Yes, It is working fine as I am able to save other data in Redis
3. No, profile is not used as of now.

Comment: Try to use any java client as jedis or lettuce to query datas from redis. It seems reading directly in-memory datas directly is not possible without using a java client, not as standard RDBMS which are allowing that.

Comment: I have already used Jedis but except StateMachine Object, other serializable objects are stored fine but not  StateMachine object.

Comment: Please check you are using that config https://stackoverflow.com/a/63998307/390462

Comment: I am not using JPA persistence but I want to use redis persistence. Is this config still applicable to redis as well?

Comment: hmm I am using JPA and it's working fine, try with it. If it's not working too we will check other things later on.